# ASP.NET DynamicData edit logic for depending fields

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I want to control some fields in a dynamic data edit page.

So for example : 
when a specific type is chosen in a combobox, other input fields should be disabled or should be set to a specific value.

How should this logic be implemented, a custom edit page ? 
Or can it be controlled from the model metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best path in Dynamic Data it's to act on the metadata side; the basic enviroment don't implement every requirement you've listed but it's relatively easy to add those functions if you check the work done here:

http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/

The main point of the DD it's the templating system: going the custom page route too easily/often, in my opinion, defy that point.

F.